# Call macro from Python script?

Tags: python, zope

One of our page templates is made up of a bunch of macros. These items are a bunch of html tables.

Now, I want a couple of these tables in a Python script to create a PDF. Is there a way call a macro from a Python script and get back the HTML that is produced?

If so, can you explain?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could create a new template including (use-macro) just the macros you want to access from python and then use z3c.pt.pagetemplate.PageTemplateFile() to render it?

Actually, it might be possible (and certainly easier) to use chameleon.zpt.template.PageTemplate('<div tal:use-macro="<your-macro-here>" />'), but I've never did this myself.

Comment: Thank you. This sounds promising. I will see where I get with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use `urllib.urlopen(url)`, pull the data from the page back to python and use `BeautifulSoup` to pull the table(s) out of the HTML... And then render that to PDF with `XHTML2PDF` (`pisa.ho`).

There might be a simpler way but for me, this would be the least stressful approach.

Comment: This was my original thought too. However, I didn't want to have to worry about permissions. The data varies depending on the role of the user. That is already built in the macros.